# Parsing in Java don't work with JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing, jsonparser

why does my Code not work

```
JSONArray dataObject = (JSONArray) parse.parse(String.valueOf(informationString));
```

It always give me the Error Code

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to class org.json.simple.JSONArray (org.json.simple.JSONObject and org.json.simple.JSONArray are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:57)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are parsing a JSON object (eg `{"a":1,"b":2,...}`) which is not a JSON array (eg `["a","b",...]`), so it can not be cast to one.

Comment: Your JSON object example is incorrect - {"a":1,"b":2,...} would be valid JSON.

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing that out. Fixed now